# How To Duplicate Product Attribute Variations in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I've hundreds of variations and around every 5 variations have the same values. The scenario is the following.

I've **Color** attribute and variations are **Red**, **Green**, **Blue**.
and **Size** attribute has: **X**, **XL**, **XXL**, **L**, **S**, **M**

I am setting attribute variations like the following.

- Red - X,
- Red - XL,
- Red - XXL,
- Red - L,
- Red - S,
- Red - M

---

- Green - X,
- Green - XL,
- Green - XXL,
- Green - L,
- Green - S,
- Green - M

---

- Blue - X,
- Blue - XL,
- Blue - XXL,
- Blue - L,
- Blue - S,
- Blue - M

For each color set, there is the same variation image, quantity, and stock limits.
How can create variations without repeating myself?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting issue. I have faced this and tried a couple of solutions. But recently I found a plugin that can duplicate your variation and image as your need.

You need to create one variation first then you can duplicate that variation 5 times so that you will get another 5 Red - X variation with all the attributes where you need to change the size only (with your example)

You can check out [this link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/variation-duplicator-for-woocommerce/),